# Как парсить drom_ru

Tags: c#, парсер

Вроде бы запрос правильно сделал `https://simferopol.drom.ru/auto/?bull_id=30681690&crossdomain_ajax_request=2&request=ajax_show_contacts&obj_id=1355835172429`
а выходит

```
{"error":false,"error_message":"","contacts":"","need_enter_captcha":"1","execute_callback":"","obj_id":""}
```

а куда уходит ответ не понимаю

Comment: `"need_enter_captcha":"1"` как бы намекает, что у них на сайте не любят веб-скрейперов. Попробуйте воспользоваться официальным API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кусок JSON `"need_enter_captcha": "1"` тонко намекает, что сайт ожидает от вас ввода капчи, и где-то на странице она отобразилась. Вероятно, вы не первый, кому пришло в голову парсить сайт, поэтому владельцы обложились капчами.

Вам, кстати, ещё повезло, что сайт так многословен. Обычно выдают ошибку 5** или 4**.

Comment: Одними и теми же словами :-P

Comment: а как такое обходить?

Comment: @Dobrotiu Вводить капчу.

Comment: пытался сделать нажатие на кнопку, через anglesharp а там если парсить страницу этой кнопки нет, возможно там эта кнопка рендерится js

Comment: @ Athari вот только я ее там не вижу

Comment: может есть еще способ, я себе бошку ломаю, понять не могу

Comment: @Athari не знаете как через anglesharp и js исполнять?

Comment: @Athari  где её взять

Comment: @Dobrotiu Вам надо понять, как работает капча, что она рендерит и на основе каких данных. Проще всего вам будет запустить полноценный браузер через какой-нибудь Selenium, и работать с тем, что отрендерилось.

Comment: @Athari ну в принципе так тоже можно